# Hibernate: Criteria Query child objects (associations) by Entity (not Id)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I would like to query a Parent object by a list of child objects with Hibernate Criteria Query. I know how to do it with IDs of the childs but not using entities directly.

This works:

```
List<Long>  listOfChildLongChildIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
listOfChildLongChildIds.add(new Long(1));
listOfChildLongChildIds.add(new Long(2));

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Parent.class);
Criteria criteriaChilds = criteria.createCriteria("childs");
criteriaChilds.add(Restrictions.in("id", listOfChildLongChildIds));
```

But how to do this, when the list contains Child Objects/Entities like this:

```
List<Child>  listOfChildEntities = new ArrayList<Child>();
listOfChildEntities.add(QueryChildFromDatabse);
listOfChildEntities.add(QueryChildFromDatabse);
```

(This means I do not use the ID of the child but only the Entitiy itself. The reason is otherwise I would have to iterate through my list of childs and extract all Ids and put them into a list what I think is most likely unnecessary. But I was not able to find any information how to query by entity lists itself):

Then the code above using

```
criteriaChilds.add(Restrictions.in("id",listOfChildEntities));
```

will throw an exception:

> Child cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Answer (score 6):

I think you should be able to do something like:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Parent.class);
criteria.createCriteria("childs","childs");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("childs.id", listOfChildLongChildIds));
```

Comment: error: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass objects to the **Restrictions.in** method.

```
Restrictions.in("childs", <childObjectslist>)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! But the problem is (at least in my test your suggestion failed!?) that the parameter you named "childs" must be (according to the docs) a property/member of the Child object.As I query by ID it must somehow be an ID.  What I needed would be a statement like: Restrictions.idIn(<childObjectslist>); Do you have any special Documentation your answer is based on? But thank in any case for your answer.

Comment: error: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4. Any clue ?